# I believe that my Area 51 commitment to the Money SE is bugged

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, commitment

Simply put, by now I certainly should have completed my commitment for Money SE. (Well, as far as Area 51 is concerned.)

http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/9466/george-marian

https://money.stackexchange.com/users/868/george-marian

I received the token for Programmers SE a while ago, despite having been more active on Money SE.  I found that rather amusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Area 51 and Money accounts are not currently associated. To associate the two accounts, click "Associate with Personal Finance and Money" on [the accounts tab of your user page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/9466?tab=accounts#tab-top).

Comment: That results in the message: "user Id 868 already associated with another account
(click on this box to dismiss)"  =/

Comment: @George You somehow got into a state where you had two separate networks of accounts.  I reassociated everything, so give it 24 hours or so and it should mark your commitment as completed.

Comment: @david Thanks. I guess this kills to birds with one stone.  I had noticed that there was an issue with some accounts not associating correctly, but forgot to pursue it.

Comment: @david It's been a while.  Still no dice.

Comment: @George We just fixed a bug which was preventing your commitment from being fulfilled. It's finally fulfilled now :)